# ActiveRecord where query not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Rails 4, SQLite3.

I have been cleaning up my queries, trying to get away from using ruby to process results. So I replaced this(which works fine):

```
 @players = Player.all.select { |m| m.team == nil}.sort_by{ |x| [x.position, x.surname] }
```

with this:

@players = Player.where(team: nil).order(position: :asc, surname: :asc)

It doesn't work. Specifically, the .where(team: nill) does not filter out players who have already been selected. I get all the players. The .order portion works fine.

I added an if statement to the view to see if player.team == nil for the players who have already been selected, and it is. In other words, the following correctly puts "its null!" next to the players who have already been selected:

```
  <% @players.each do |player| %>
   <tr>
   <% if player.team == nil %>
   <td> its null!</td>
   <%else%>
   <%end%> 

  <td><td><%= player.first_name %> <%= player.surname %></td></td>
  <td><%= player.position %></td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
```

so why isn't my query filtering them out?

The query thats generated is:

```
SELECT "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."team_id" IS NULL  ORDER BY "players"."position" ASC, "players"."surname" ASC
```

Here are my models:

```
 class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :team, through: :ownership
 has_one :ownership

 validates :first_name, presence: true
 validates :surname, presence: true
 validates :position, presence: true

 def full_name
 "#{first_name} #{surname}"
 end
 end

 class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :ownerships
 has_many :players, through: :ownerships

 validates :name, presence: true

 validates :division, presence: true
 end

 class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :player
 belongs_to :team

 validates :round, :pick, :team_id, presence: true
 end
```

This is the schema:

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150923185333) do

 create_table "ownerships", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "round"
t.integer  "pick"
t.integer  "team_id"
t.integer  "player_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "ownerships", ["player_id"], name:  "index_ownerships_on_player_id"
add_index "ownerships", ["team_id"], name: "index_ownerships_on_team_id"

create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "position"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.string   "surname"
t.integer  "team_id"
end

create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "division"
t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
t.string   "logo_file_name"
t.string   "logo_content_type"
t.integer  "logo_file_size"
t.datetime "logo_updated_at"
end

end
```

Comment: It may not make a difference, but try being explicit about the column name by saying `.where(team_id: nil)`. Another thing you may try is writing the raw SQL like this `.where("team_id IS NULL")`. Hope it helps!

Comment: @DavidMeza: That won't help since `players.team_id` isn't used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the SQL generated by the query, it probably includes something like:

```
SELECT players.* WHERE players.team_id IS NULL
```

This would work *if* `team` was defined via a `belongs_to :team` association on `Player`, but its not: its defined via a `has_one :team` with a `through: :ownership` option. This means you'll need to join to the `teams` table through the `ownership` table and select the records with no associated `teams` records. Since you'll need to use a left join, you have to write the join "manually":

```
@players = Player.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN ownerships ON ownerships.player_id = players.id")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN teams ON ownerships.team_id = teams.id")
  .where("teams.id IS NULL").order(position: :asc, surname: :asc)
```

You probably want to remove the extraneous column `team_id` to avoid this kind of confusion:

```
remove_column :players, :team_id
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! Your explanation has got me thinking about how my association are put together. Excellent answer.